# Python: Declare list structure avoiding duplicate references

Tags: python, list, reference, declaration

I need an empty list with the following structure so I can later populate it without getting out of range errors:

`[5[2[]]]`

i.e.:
`[[[], []], [[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]`

So I tried declaring it this way:
`[[[]]*n]*m` / `n=2`, `m=5`

But `*` is copying references, so if i do something like this:

```
>>> foo = [[[]]*2]*5
>>> foo
   [[[], []], [[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]

>>> foo[3][0] = 1
>>> foo
   [[1, []], [1, []], [1, []], [1, []]]
```

The assigned value gets copied to all sub-lists with the same reference.

I can fix this by declaring `foo`'s sizes "statically" like:

`foo = [[[], []], [[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]`

But I need a parametric way like the previous example.

I would like to know if there's a parametric pythonic/compact way of of declaring and empty list of lists (like with `n` and `m` in the example), where all its elements have individual references.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[[] for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: Use a list-comp as mentioned in the dupe to create *new* lists at each position. In your case you should use `foo = [[[] for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(5)]`

Comment: Nice! that can work out this way:
`foo = [[[] for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]`
Can you think of a more compact/readable version?